# JDA retrieve messages on a specific date

Tags: java, discord, bots

So actually I would like to order with 2 args like !stat 11/18/21

And this command will allow a discord bot to count the number of messages that were posted in a channel on that specific date. Kind of like CTRL + F "during: ... ... ...

The problem is that with a lot of research I found nothing concrete.

So if anyone would help me out and give me some pseudo code as an example or point me to a place to learn how to handle time on JDA

I hope I was clear enough :(
(since I'm French and completely bad at English, I had to use google trad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt at using `java.time` and `channel.getIterableHistory()` to efficiently iterate and count the messages:

```java
public CompletableFuture<Integer> getCountDuring(String dateString, MessageChannel channel) {
  // Parse the date from the input
  DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy");
  LocalDateTime date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormat).atStartOfDay();
  // Get the boundary of the time as instant
  Instant startOfDayDT = Instant.ofEpochSecond(date.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC));
  Instant endOfDayDT = Instant.ofEpochSecond(date.plusDays(1).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC));
  // Create pseudo-snowflake for the message to start from
  long endOfDay = TimeUtil.getDiscordTimestamp(endOfDayDT.toEpochMilli());

  // Use atomic counter
  AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

  CompletableFuture<Integer> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
  channel.getIterableHistory()
    .skipTo(endOfDay) // start iterating backwards from the end of the day
    .forEachAsync(message -> {
      // Check message creation time is in range of day
      Instant time = message.getTimeCreated().toInstant();
      if (time.isBefore(endOfDayDT) && time.isAfter(startOfDayDT)) {
        count.incrementAndGet();
      }
      // Stop iterating when this is false
      return time.isAfter(startOfDayDT);
    })
    .thenRun(() -> future.complete(count.get())) // yield the counter at the end
    .exceptionally(error -> { // catch errors
      future.completeExceptionally(error);
      return null;
    });
  return future;
}

// Example usage
getCountDuring("11/18/21", channel).thenAccept(count -> {
  System.out.println("Counted " + count + " messages on 11/18/21"); 
});
```

I haven't really tested if this works, lmk if you have any issues with it and I can take a look.